# ZK grouped listbox performance

Tags: java, web-applications, listbox, zk

I'm currently working on a ZK screen with a Listbox that contains groups.  Since you can't (as far as I know) use DataBinder to set the model with a GroupsModel, I'm manually creating one and calling setModel.  To configure the Listgroups and Listitems I need to create a ListitemRenderer, which I've done.

The problem is that whenever you open or close a group on the screen, it communicates with the server to set the group as being open, and calls the ListitemRenderer again for every visible row.  This results in a laggy interface for the user.

Is it possible to get ZK to cache the contents of the Listgroups and Listitems on the client such that opening/closing groups will not talk to the server and doesn't render every row again?  With this system, the contents of the rows will not change until the user performs another search, or if they drag/drop items.

Edit:
I ended up just building the Listgroups and Listitems myself and adding them with appendChild.  No need for a model or renderer, so everything is done on the client meaning it's very snappy.  It'd still be nice to know how it could be done with a model/renderer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you can use [renderall()](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/api/Listbox.html#renderAll%28%29) method.

e,g
    myListbox.getItemRenderer().renderAll()

IMO, if your model contains a lot of data, this action will maybe slower than default action.